# Django-Using distinct on a specific field with annotate

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm, django-aggregation

I have following models:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class PostView(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, related_name='views', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(), related_name='my_views')
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

I want to get posts ordered by number of unique views.
I get the posts ordered by views by following code:

```
filters = {
    'created__date__gte': datetime.datetime(year=2020, month=1, day=1),
    'created__date__lte': datetime.datetime(year=2021, month=1, day=1),
}

qs = Post.objects.all().annotate(
    total_views=Count('views', filter=Q(**filters))
).order_by('-total_views')
```

above code will calculate all views as `total_views`. I want to get unique views by `user`.
Is it possible to do that with ORM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of counting `views`, you can count `views__user` directly and apply a `distinct=True` on this aggregation:

```
qs = Post.objects.all().annotate(
    total_views=Count('views__user', distinct=True, filter=Q(**filters))
).order_by('-total_views')
```

Comment: what about unique views by hours of day? `qs = PostView.objects.filter(**filters ).annotate(hour=TruncHour('created')).values('hour').annotate(c=Count('user_id', distinct=True)).values('hour', 'c')`. this is not working.